# Better to call C executable functions or load C functions and call them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, interface, binding

I have executables written in C and I want to call those executables from a javascript library. Is it better to have the executables separated from the javascript library or to be part of the javascript library ?

The former would look like this

```
let foo = "C:/Users/lala/foo.exe";
let params ="-v -f";

command: `** ${foo} $(params)`,
process: spawn(foo, params),
```

In contrary the latter I would have to load the C/C++ library to javascript and call the native functions from javascript explained in this link: https://medium.com/jspoint/a-simple-guide-to-load-c-c-code-into-node-js-javascript-applications-3fcccf54fd32

Can someone please tell me orios and cons about them ?

Comment: _"... load the C/C++ library..."_ you say _"...I have executables written in C..."_ do you have libraries ?

Comment: Yes ! Currently it is in the .exe format but I can convert to its library form.